# Inserting lines in a multiline command using a for loop in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting, multiline

I have a bash script which executes a multi-line command multiple times and I am changing the some values on each iteration. Here is my code below:

```
for (( peer=1; peer<=$nodesNum;peer++ ))
do  
   echo "Starting peer $peer"

nodeos -p eosio -d /eosio_data/node$peer --config-dir /eosio_data/node$peer --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:$http  \
--p2p-listen-endpoint=127.0.0.1:$p2p --access-control-allow-origin=* \
-p "user$peer" --http-validate-host=false --signature-provider=EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV=KEY:5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3  \
 --max-transaction-time=1000 --genesis-json /eosio_data/genesis.json --wasm-runtime=wabt --max-clients=2000 -e  \
--plugin eosio::chain_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin  \
 --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--p2p-peer-address localhost:8888 \
 &>eosio_data/logs/nodeos_stderr$p2p.log &   \
sleep 1
http=$((http+1))
p2p=$((p2p+1))
done
```

I need to add a --p2p-peer-address localhost:$((9010 + $peer)) command multiple times for each peer as part of the multi-line command. I new to bash scripting and I couldn't find a similar example.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: To be clear, is there *one* call to `nodeos` that requires multiple `--p2p-peer-address` options?

Comment: Or are then `nodesNum` separate calls to `nodeos`, each of which requires multiple `--p2p-peer-address` options? (And are the 90xx options in addition to the 8888 option?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you need, but I think it's something like the following. An array of `--p2p-peer-address` options is created, then incorporated
into the larger set of common options. Each call to `nodeos` then has some peer-specific options in addition to the common options.

```
# for example
HTTP_BASE=8080
P2P_BASE=12345

# Set of --p2p-peer-address options for shared by all calls.
for ((peer=1; peer <= $nodesNum; peer++)); do 
    peer_args+=( 
      --p2p-peer-address
      localhost:$((9010+$peer)) 
    )
done

# These are the same for all calls
fixed_args=(
    -p eosio
    "--access-control-allow-origin=*"
    --http-validate-host=false
    --signature-provider=EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV=KEY:5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3
    --max-transaction-time=1000
    --genesis-json /eosio_data/genesis.json
    --wasm-runtime=wabt
    --max-clients=2000
    -e
    --plugin eosio::chain_plugin
    --plugin eosio::producer_plugin
    --plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin
    --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin
    --p2p-peer-address localhost:8888
    "${peer_args[@]}"
)

for ((peer=1; peer<=$nodesNum; peer++)); do
    # Call-specific arguments, followed by common arguments.
    # $peer is either incorporated into each argument value
    nodeos -d /eosio_data/node$peer \
           --config-dir /eosio_data/node$peer \
           --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:$((HTTP_BASE + $peer)) \
           --p2p-listen-endpoint=127.0.0.1:$((P2P_BASE + $peer)) \
           -p "user$peer" \
           "${fixed_args[@]}" \
           &> eosio_data/logs/nodeos_stderr$((P2P_BASE + $peer)).log & 
    sleep 1
done
```

---

To avoid having each instance of `nodeos` try to connect to itself, build `peer_args` anew on each iteration of the loop. Remove `"${peer_args[@]}"` from the definition of `fixed_args`, then adjust the main loop like so:

```
for ((peer=1; peer <= $nodesNum; peer++)); do
    peer_args=()
    for ((neighbor=1; neighbor <= $nodesNum; neighbor++)); do
        (( neighbor == peer )) && continue
        peer_args+=( --p2p-peer-address localhost:$((9010+peer)) )
    done

    nodeos -d /eosio_data/node$peer \
           --config-dir /eosio_data/node$peer \
           --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:$((HTTP_BASE + $peer)) \
           --p2p-listen-endpoint=127.0.0.1:$((P2P_BASE + $peer)) \
           -p "user$peer" \
           "${fixed_args[@]}" \
           "${peer_args[@]}" \
           &> eosio_data/logs/nodeos_stderr$((P2P_BASE + $peer)).log & 
     sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is exactly what I was looking for. However, one small problem arose - since currently I am adding all the addresses in the peer_args array, this includes the p2p address of the current node. This in turn invokes a connection monitor every 30 seconds since the node cannot connect to itself. Is it possible to change the peer_args dynamically, excluding the one?

Comment: Probably the simplest thing to do will be to build `peer_args` from scratch just before each call to `nodeos`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were very close.  The expression you authored `--p2p-peer-address localhost:$((9010 + $peer))` can be inserted into your nodeos call as follows:

```
for (( peer=1; peer<=$nodesNum;peer++ ))
do  
   echo "Starting peer $peer"

  nodeos -p eosio -d /eosio_data/node$peer \
   --config-dir /eosio_data/node$peer \
   --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:$http  \
   --p2p-listen-endpoint=127.0.0.1:$p2p \
   --access-control-allow-origin=* \
   -p "user$peer" \
   --http-validate-host=false \
   --signature-provider=EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV=KEY:5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3  \
   --max-transaction-time=1000 --genesis-json /eosio_data/genesis.json --wasm-runtime=wabt --max-clients=2000 -e  \
   --plugin eosio::chain_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin  \
   --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
   --p2p-peer-address localhost:$((9010 + $peer)) &>eosio_data/logs/nodeos_stderr$p2p.log & 

  sleep 1
  http=$((http+1))
  p2p=$((p2p+1))
done
```

Comment: Sorry I belive  I did not explain it very clearly. My problem was that I had to add that --p2p-peer-address line multiple times  on each iteration (i.e so that each node has the p2p addresses of all the other nodes). This would only add the address of the current peer to the command.

Comment: Hi Aleksi, I was certain I was missing something since the solution I proposed was so obvious - but sometimes the best way to move forward is to make a mistake and be corrected.  I'm glad you got the help you needed from chepner.